# Produce a 'Tuple' like output from a method but with lists as members of said tuple

Tags: java

I'm required to create a function that will produce multiple outputs. There are 4 outputs of 'double' type and two outputs of a specific object type. I don't want to output them all individually, nor do I want to put them in their own class (it seems wasteful to create a class just for this one method that won't be used anywhere else). So instead I thought to create a Tuple-like class that can take List types as inputs:

```
/**
 * This class will create a Tuple-like data structure where both inputs can be lists. 
 * @param <A>
 * @param <B>
 */
public class ListPair<A extends List, B extends List> {
  public final A a;
  public final B b;

  public ListPair(A a, B b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

The intent being that my function can now simply output this class.

I haven't worked with Java before (most of my experience is with C#) so I'm not sure if creating a class like this would be the best way to go. Any alternative recommendations would be welcome.

Comment: I'd say a simple class would be the ideal solution. It's not wasteful. Any decent IDE will create most of the class for you.

Comment: yeah, like Federico said, just create the class, i think it is the best way

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca not sure I agree about it not being wasteful. There are several instances in my project where I need to implement  methods that return multiple values. Many of them are completely unrelated to each other in terms of number and type of output, so if I go down the 'bespoke' class route, I'll need to form up classes for all of them,  which seems more wasteful than having this one generic type that can handle lots of things for me. 

Is there another reason to prefer the class route over this one ? I'm not well versed in Java so might be missing something.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "wasteful" means to you. I create what I need to make my code readable, first. A class carries information about what its members are meant to represent and what it itself represents (because both the class and its members have meaningful names). A pair (or any tuple) doesn't. If you need to privilege readability, go for a custom class. If you don't care (for example because you just need to use it locally inside a method, take the value and then forget it ever existed) go for the pair.